# Query data in MongoDB by date (timestamp) using python

Tags: python, mongodb, timestamp

I am trying to query data by `timestamp` in a `MongoDB` using python, but I'm receiving nothing.
I tried to query using other keys (`houseColor` or `houseId` ) and it worked, but when I tried to query by `timestamp` It did not work.

**Am I missing something?**

My code looks like this:

```
def filter_by_date(client):
    db_name = client['db']
    collection_name = db_name["collection"]
    data = collection_name.find_one({"timestamp": "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00"})
    print(data)
```

The data in `MongoDB` looks like this:

```
id: 001
houseColor: "blue"
houseId: "001"
houseName: "sky"
state: "flo"
cost: 100000
timestamp: 2022-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

Comment: Maybe on mongoDB your date is of type `ISODate` and in your query your input is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easy, the query using python looks like this:

```
def filter_by_date(client):
    db_name = client['db']
    collection_name = db_name["collection"]
    query = {'timestamp': datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0)}
    data = collection_name.find_one(query)
    print(data)
```

So if you want yo query only one date you should have something like this:

```
query = {'timestamp': datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0)}
```

If it is a range of dates, the query looks like this:

```
query = {'timestamp': {"$gte": datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0), "$lt": datetime(2019, 6, 30, 0, 0)}}
```